# Login before submit a form Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.1 for a new project, I would like to know if it is possible the next:

Fill a form on `PoolController@getCreate` and submit it to `PoolController@postCreate`
But before submit , the user must connect, So he will be redirect to  `UserController@getLogin` and finnally he return to `PoolController@postCreate`.

What do you think, and there is a way to make that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your request follows the following suite:

`[FORM]->[LOGIN/AUTH]->[FORM]->Submit.`

In which case you want to carry the state of your form over using `Input::old()`

See Docs:
http://laravel.com/docs/requests#old-input

Comment: I added a `auth` filter `before` FORM submit to connect user and continue submit but it redirect user to [FORM] not to [FORM]->Submit

Comment: So you want to submit the form programatically?